# QDBus problem: getting org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod, but method exists

Tags: linux, ubuntu, methods, dbus

I'm programming C++ on Ubuntu, using QDBus and I've got the following code snippet:

```
this->m_cRemoteInterface = new QDBusInterface("org.my.service", "/data", "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get"); 

QDBusReply<uint64_t> cResult = m_cRemoteInterface->call("property1");
```

The code throws the following error:

> org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod:
>   Method "property1" with
>   signature "" on interface
>   "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get"
>   doesn't exist

But when I issue the following command in a shell, it returns the correct value:

> dbus org.my.service /data org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get "
>   " property1

What could I do wrong?

Thanks in advance, emi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an afternoon of trail and error:

I declared

> org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get

as interface, which is not right.

I had to use only

> org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties

as interface and then

> call("Get", " ", "property1");

May this help someone. :).